# Did the Bitcoin network reduce spam?

Tags: satoshi-nakamoto, spam, botnets

In an 2008-11-03 email, Satoshi Nakamoto hypothesized that Bitcoin could actually reduce spam by making botnets more valuable for being part of the Bitcoin network than spamming:

> The Bitcoin network might actually reduce spam by diverting zombie
> farms to generating bitcoins instead

Was there any research done to say if this actually occurred or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Was there any research done to say if this actually occurred or not?

No.

---

It is, of course, impossible to prove a negative.

However I consider it obvious that the sort of hardware used for botnets is not the sort of hardware used nowadays for hashing. **Specialised SHA256 ASICs are not repurposed spambots**.

During the era of GPU mining, I seriously doubt there was any reduction in home gaming. Merely many disgruntled addicts paying over the top for GPUs or gnashing their teeth at unavailability of bleeding edge GPUs. I doubt a significant number gave up world of warcraft etc.

Consequently I doubt the specialist market for Bitcoin mining hardware caused any measurable reduction of email spamming.

Consequently, I'd be a little surprised if any serious researcher thought it worthwhile them spending significant time carrying out rigorous research on this subject and reporting on it.

Comment: Yeah, there was a brief influx of botnet hashpower in 2011, but shortly after that, CPU mining became unprofitable, even for botnets.